# Curious badge not rewarded

Tags: support, badges

I have asked almost > 10 questions on Stack Overflow and all are having positive votes, but I have still not received the *[Curious](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399)* badge.

As per the *Curious* badge description:

> Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a
>   positive question record

It is also showing in my profile that I have asked 10/5 well-received questions.

[image]

But still I have not been awarded that badge and showing me that this badge is recommended.

What might be the possible reason for this?

Comment: To which site are your referring to? Stack Overflow? MSE?

Comment: @Mureinik its about stackoverflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you must "ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, *and maintain a positive question record*." You have done the former but not the latter.

[As explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67399/238426):

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`. Questions that have been downvoted and closed and deleted count three times in this calculation!

In your case, the calculation is `(24 - 5 - 2 - 11)/24 = 0.25 < 0.5`. Because you're short of the `0.5` threshold, you haven't gotten the badge yet.

Comment: Excuse me if this question is a bit stupid, but does "ask a well-received question on 5 separate days" mean "ask 5 questions with positive score each"?