# Badge progress like 29/5 (e.g. for curious badge) is misleading

Tags: support, bug, badges, badge-progress

**Summary:** My question is not about why I have not got the badge, but rather the misleading progress display.

There are quite some posts about this topic. Most of them are marked either duplicate or closed. This topic is slightly different here is why,

To get curious badge a user must Ask a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintain a positive question record. Agreed!

The formula to calculate if I am eligible for this badge is `total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`. Totally fine!

The best example what I can give why I think the count is shown wrong is I can't have 7 apples out of 5! How can I have 29/5 on the badge? I think the way the numbers are displaying is misleading.

Here are the few questions which talk about this issue but they are answered with you don't have +ve track. This answer doesn't really help. Again, how can I have 29 apples out of 5?

[Curious badge not rewarded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273420/curious-badge-not-rewarded)

[Curious badge bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256469/curious-badge-bug)

Comment: You asked 29 questions, but you don't have a positive question record.

Comment: You can't have 29/5 questions, but you can have 29/5 *required* questions.

Comment: @Gothdo: Yes. That doesn't explain why is it 29/5 it should be 0/5.

Comment: No. You met requirement 1, but not requirement 2. That doesn't mean requirement 1 is wrong.

Comment: @PatrickHofman : The badge which is showing visually should somehow incorporate the second requirement as well right? That's what my question is about.

Comment: No, that would mean too much information for quite some badges.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Agreed, I need condition-1 & condition-2 to be true for getting a score of 1. The number 29 should not be shown up in the first place in my opinion... The count should be only those which meet both the conditions.

Comment: Assuming the hardest part is asking *X* questions, that could be the value you want to see, not the 'hard to understand' calculation.

Comment: Agree it's misleading and reopened the question, but what you suggest instead?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Yes. That is the value I want to see. The calculation can be abstracted... I think the question is not duplicate of the flagged question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: As a user, it is convenient for me to see only the counts which match the criteria. For example, if I need 4 more +ve questions then the count should be 1 regardless of how many questions I have asked in the past. If I need 7 more questions, the count should be 0 not -2. This would be my suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps adding a few tags like 'bug', 'support' might get the attention of someone who can do something about the question.

Comment: Requirement 2 isn't exactly something that can be calculated on an individual question basis. Requirement 1 is able to do that, which is why it's 29/5: You have asked a question a well received question on 29 days out of the 5 required. The second requirement, however, is not a "per question" tally, but looks at _your account as a whole._ This means it can't decide that you don't have enough questions just because your account as a whole does not have a "positive question record." So showing 29/5 instead of 0/5 and jumping immediately to 5/5 on completion makes sense, at least to me. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Addressing your statement that the tracker should show you the second condition, I'm not sure how they could incorporate it better than they have without making things crowded or ugly. They _do_ show it [if you click the progress bar in your activity page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6K6w.png) But that's not exactly prominent and helps lead to this confusion. They _could_ in theory put it below the progress bar everywhere it displays... But that might be hard to do without taking up too much space or looking ugly, if other badges have more of these to show.